# Higgs Bundle with value not in canonical bundle.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory

I read an old paper by Donagi (Principal bundle over elliptic fibrations), and he mentioned the possibility for Higgs bundle to take value in an elliptic curve or vector bundle rather than the standard one defined by Hitchin.

I didn't find a reference on this. Also, I'm curious about what happens the Hitching equation in this case...

Thank you.